# Lein deps command can't find artifacts

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm trying to get lein up and running. But for some reason I'm having tons of issues. I'm performing this on Windows 7. I downloaded lein and did the following:

`lein self-install`

this ran correctly

Then I created a project via

`lein new helloworld`

Then I got deps via

`lein deps`

and I get this:

```
Downloading: org/clojure/clojure/1.2.0/clojure-1.2.0.pom from central
Downloading: org/clojure/clojure/1.2.0/clojure-1.2.0.pom from clojure
Downloading: org/clojure/clojure/1.2.0/clojure-1.2.0.pom from clojure-snapshots
Downloading: org/clojure/clojure/1.2.0/clojure-1.2.0.pom from clojars
Downloading: org/clojure/clojure/1.2.0/clojure-1.2.0.pom from central
Downloading: org/clojure/clojure-contrib/1.2.0/clojure-contrib-1.2.0.pom from central
Downloading: org/clojure/clojure-contrib/1.2.0/clojure-contrib-1.2.0.pom from clojure
Downloading: org/clojure/clojure-contrib/1.2.0/clojure-contrib-1.2.0.pom from clojure-snapshots
Downloading: org/clojure/clojure-contrib/1.2.0/clojure-contrib-1.2.0.pom from clojars
Downloading: org/clojure/clojure-contrib/1.2.0/clojure-contrib-1.2.0.pom from central
Downloading: org/clojure/clojure/1.2.0/clojure-1.2.0.jar from central
Downloading: org/clojure/clojure/1.2.0/clojure-1.2.0.jar from clojure
Downloading: org/clojure/clojure/1.2.0/clojure-1.2.0.jar from clojure-snapshots
Downloading: org/clojure/clojure/1.2.0/clojure-1.2.0.jar from clojars
Downloading: org/clojure/clojure/1.2.0/clojure-1.2.0.jar from central
Downloading: org/clojure/clojure-contrib/1.2.0/clojure-contrib-1.2.0.jar from central
Downloading: org/clojure/clojure-contrib/1.2.0/clojure-contrib-1.2.0.jar from clojure
Downloading: org/clojure/clojure-contrib/1.2.0/clojure-contrib-1.2.0.jar from clojure-snapshots
Downloading: org/clojure/clojure-contrib/1.2.0/clojure-contrib-1.2.0.jar from clojars
Downloading: org/clojure/clojure-contrib/1.2.0/clojure-contrib-1.2.0.jar from central
Exception in thread "main" Unable to resolve artifact: Missing:
----------
1) org.clojure:clojure:jar:1.2.0

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command:
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.clojure -DartifactId=clojure -Dversion=1.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/t
o/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.clojure -DartifactId=clojure -Dversion=1.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/
file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency:
        1) org.apache.maven:super-pom:jar:2.0
        2) org.clojure:clojure:jar:1.2.0

2) org.clojure:clojure-contrib:jar:1.2.0

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command:
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.clojure -DartifactId=clojure-contrib -Dversion=1.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile
=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.clojure -DartifactId=clojure-contrib -Dversion=1.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/
path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency:
        1) org.apache.maven:super-pom:jar:2.0
        2) org.clojure:clojure-contrib:jar:1.2.0

----------
2 required artifacts are missing.

for artifact:
  org.apache.maven:super-pom:jar:2.0

from the specified remote repositories:
  clojure (http://build.clojure.org/releases),
  clojars (http://clojars.org/repo/),
  clojure-snapshots (http://build.clojure.org/snapshots),
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

 (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5440)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5391)
        at clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2382)
        at clojure.main$eval_opt.invoke(main.clj:235)
        at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:254)
        at clojure.main$script_opt.invoke(main.clj:270)
        at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:354)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:458)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:377)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:174)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:482)
        at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: Unable to resolve artifact: Missing:
----------
1) org.clojure:clojure:jar:1.2.0

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command:
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.clojure -DartifactId=clojure -Dversion=1.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/t
o/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.clojure -DartifactId=clojure -Dversion=1.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/
file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency:
        1) org.apache.maven:super-pom:jar:2.0
        2) org.clojure:clojure:jar:1.2.0

2) org.clojure:clojure-contrib:jar:1.2.0

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command:
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.clojure -DartifactId=clojure-contrib -Dversion=1.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile
=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.clojure -DartifactId=clojure-contrib -Dversion=1.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/
path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency:
        1) org.apache.maven:super-pom:jar:2.0
        2) org.clojure:clojure-contrib:jar:1.2.0

----------
2 required artifacts are missing.

for artifact:
  org.apache.maven:super-pom:jar:2.0

from the specified remote repositories:
  clojure (http://build.clojure.org/releases),
  clojars (http://clojars.org/repo/),
  clojure-snapshots (http://build.clojure.org/snapshots),
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)


        at org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.DependenciesTask.doExecute(DependenciesTask.java:175)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.AbstractArtifactTask.execute(AbstractArtifactTask.java:678)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:90)
        at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeNoArgInstanceMember(Reflector.java:265)
        at leiningen.deps$deps.invoke(deps.clj:79)
        at leiningen.deps$deps.invoke(deps.clj:90)
        at leiningen.deps$deps.invoke(deps.clj:91)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:365)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:482)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:542)
        at leiningen.core$apply_task.invoke(core.clj:191)
        at leiningen.core$_main.doInvoke(core.clj:250)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:138)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:542)
        at leiningen.core$_main.invoke(core.clj:255)
        at user$eval175.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5424)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.MultipleArtifactsNotFoundException: Missing:
----------
1) org.clojure:clojure:jar:1.2.0

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command:
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.clojure -DartifactId=clojure -Dversion=1.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/t
o/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.clojure -DartifactId=clojure -Dversion=1.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/
file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency:
        1) org.apache.maven:super-pom:jar:2.0
        2) org.clojure:clojure:jar:1.2.0

2) org.clojure:clojure-contrib:jar:1.2.0

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command:
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.clojure -DartifactId=clojure-contrib -Dversion=1.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile
=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.clojure -DartifactId=clojure-contrib -Dversion=1.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/
path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency:
        1) org.apache.maven:super-pom:jar:2.0
        2) org.clojure:clojure-contrib:jar:1.2.0

----------
2 required artifacts are missing.

for artifact:
  org.apache.maven:super-pom:jar:2.0

from the specified remote repositories:
  clojure (http://build.clojure.org/releases),
  clojars (http://clojars.org/repo/),
  clojure-snapshots (http://build.clojure.org/snapshots),
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)


        at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveTransitively(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:3
24)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.DependenciesTask.doExecute(DependenciesTask.java:170)
        ... 32 more
PS C:\clojureprj\helloworld> lein deps 2> out.txt
An error has occurred while processing the Maven artifact tasks.
 Diagnosis:

Unable to resolve artifact: Missing:
----------
1) org.clojure:clojure:jar:1.2.0

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command:
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.clojure -DartifactId=clojure -Dversion=1.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/t
o/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.clojure -DartifactId=clojure -Dversion=1.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/
file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency:
        1) org.apache.maven:super-pom:jar:2.0
        2) org.clojure:clojure:jar:1.2.0

2) org.clojure:clojure-contrib:jar:1.2.0

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command:
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.clojure -DartifactId=clojure-contrib -Dversion=1.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile
=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.clojure -DartifactId=clojure-contrib -Dversion=1.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/
path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency:
        1) org.apache.maven:super-pom:jar:2.0
        2) org.clojure:clojure-contrib:jar:1.2.0

----------
2 required artifacts are missing.

for artifact:
  org.apache.maven:super-pom:jar:2.0

from the specified remote repositories:
  clojure (http://build.clojure.org/releases),
  clojars (http://clojars.org/repo/),
  clojure-snapshots (http://build.clojure.org/snapshots),
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)




PS C:\clojureprj\helloworld>
```

What am I doing wrong? Can lein really not find Clojure? I'm sure I'm missing something here.

---- Edit -----

Here's the project.clj I'm using:

```
(defproject helloworld "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.2.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojure-contrib "1.2.0"]])
```

Comment: could you include the project.clj that was generated by lein new. this will help a lot

Comment: updated to show the project.clj

Comment: i tested your project.clj with todays leiningen and it works. must be one of the more interesting maven problems.

Comment: could you run lein pom and post the generated pom.xml. this will list the repos it is trying to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gota love Maven error messages ;)

this is maven speak for "failed to download the version you asked for"...

this can be caused by:

- specifying a version of a dependency that does not exist in project.clj (unlikely since you just auto-generated it)
- broken dependencies by a package maintainer.
- bugs in leiningen (rare these days).
- garbage left over in your maven cache (try deleting it, sorry i don't know where it lives in windows)
- manually specified maven repositories other than the standard central ones globally (rare)

try downloading the latest version of lein, deleting your maven cache, running it again and then complaining on the leiningen mailing list.

Comment: I'm accepting this as it helped me find the issue. I think the problem comes from the fact that my home folder is being re-routed to a network drive (aka Windows Roaming Profile). cmd.exe doesn't allow UNC paths (eg. \\fooserver\share\bar) so that was causing issues. In the end I created a local user without a roaming profile and lein started working more normally.

Answer (score 0):

As clojure jar is actually [available](http://build.clojure.org/releases/org/clojure/clojure/1.2.0/) in one of the specified repositories, it might be the case that network is not properly configured. If you're behind a proxy, configure maven [properly](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html) and retry.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message - what was broken for me was I specified the wrong jar dependency (copied from another source). You can view available artefacts here:

http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cclojure

I hope this helps someone